# assigning comparer to ListViewItemSorter

Tags: c#, sorting, listview

I want to sort a ListView control in C# based on columns. I have created ColumnClickEventHandler:

```
    private void contactsListView_ColumnClick(object sender, ColumnClickEventArgs e)
    {
        contactsListView.ListViewItemSorter = new ListViewItemComparer(e.Column);
        contactsListView.Sort();
    }
```

Where ListViewItemComparer class looks like this:

```
   class ListViewItemComparer : IComparer<ListViewItem>
{
    private int col;
    public ListViewItemComparer()
    {
        col = 0;
    }
    public ListViewItemComparer(int column)
    {
        col = column;
    }
    public int Compare(ListViewItem x, ListViewItem y)
    {
        int returnVal = -1;
        returnVal = String.Compare(x.SubItems[col].Text, y.SubItems[col].Text);
        return returnVal;
    }
}
```

This code won't compile cause contactsListView.ListViewItemSorter is type IComparer and class ListViewItemComparer is IComparer.

Is there a way to explicitly cast one to the other? Or just do sorting another way?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The generic `IComparer<T>` and the non-generic `IComparer` aren't convertible from one another.

Maybe your `ListViewItemComparer` should implement the non-generic `IComparer` instead?

Comment: You are right. I forgot to use System.Collections (I had just System.Collections.Generic). That's why when I saw missing IComparer<> type I've just put it in :P
Thanks and happy programming :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the comparer class should be I`Comparer, not IComparer<type>`.
[here is an article](http://blogs.interknowlogy.com/joelrumerman/archive/2007/04/03/12497.aspx) that might help, it uses the SortDescriptions.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
class ListViewItemComparer : IComparer
```

not

```
class ListViewItemComparer : IComparer<ListViewItem>
```